# Почему не ставится vue cli?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, npm

После команды `npm install -g @vue/cli`
   в консоли

```js
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue -> C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\bin\vue.js

> core-js@3.2.1 postinstall C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\core-js
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

"node" ▒▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒७▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒譥▒
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒, ▒ᯮ▒▒塞▒▒ ▒ணࠬ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ 䠩▒▒▒.
"ignore"

> protobufjs@6.8.8 postinstall C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\protobufjs
> node scripts/postinstall

"node" ▒▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒७▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒譥▒
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒, ▒ᯮ▒▒塞▒▒ ▒ணࠬ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ 䠩▒▒▒.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! protobufjs@6.8.8 postinstall: `node scripts/postinstall`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the protobufjs@6.8.8 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 0):

Запустить с правами Администратора

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Node.js
```

Node.js command promtpt -> Запуск от Администратора